# Error when attempting to decode JSON Web Token returned from own backend API -

Tags: c#, jwt, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly application with an ASP.Net Core Web API backend.

The app uses JSON Web Tokens, which are created and returned by the backend API as part of a successful authentication by the user.

I have a problem once the JWT has been returned to the browser, and Blazor is attempting to decode the contents of the token.

In my development environment, this works beautifully, and decodes all the encoded information within the token.

However, when attempting to run both the API and Blazor Webassembly front end on the web server, the following exception is generated when attempting to decode the token:

```
EXCEPTION: IDX12729: Unable to decode the header 'System.String' as Base64Url encoded string. jwtEncodedString: 'System.String'
```

The exception is generated by the following code:

```
var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var jwtToken = jwtHandler.ReadJwtToken(jwtTokenString);
```

> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.8.0.0

The actual token is below:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.klbdvnjikSbnjr8q_7d4vxMsxajPJ3nY3yiDevJCdHo
```

I have validated the token (via https://devtoolzone.com/decoder/jwt ) and everything looks ok.

[image: Contents of Token]

Can anyone offer any guidance?

Comment: I test the bearer token with ReadJwtToken, but no exception. Can you share more code and what extension you used?

Comment: I'm not sure what other code I can post that would be relevant.  I've just tried taking the API call out of the equation, hard-coded the token string in the Blazor app, and attempted to decode it in isolation after the app has initialised.  I get exactly the same result, i.e. when running in localhost via Visual Studio 2019, it decodes perfectly; when running it from the webserver, the same error as above.

The app uses System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.8.0.0.

The only thing that is different is the fact that it's being served by a web server. Could it be some IIS config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further investigation, there was an Inner Exception that I hadn't spotted which read:

```
Unable to find a default constructor to use for type System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtHeader
```

This lead me to this known issue on Github: https://github.com/mono/linker/issues/870

In summary, there is a workaround, by including the following code in program.cs after builder.Build():

```
_ = new JwtHeader();
_ = new JwtPayload();
```

I don't begin to understand what the issue is, but am just happy that now everything works as expected.